# Drop down Selection -> Search database

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, drop-down-menu

How would I search an SQL database when a user makes a selection in a dropdown list. I know how to change/add text to areas using some javascript but not with a SQL search as well.

Ideally I don't want to be changing pages in this process as I'm thinking they won't be sticking on a single option in the drop down for long.

Cheers in advance. =)

Comment: what back-end are you using? ASP.NET, MVC, django, PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an `onchange` event listener to the dropdown box. When the user selects an option, an AJAX ([XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest)) should be send to the server. A serverside script, a PHP page for example, should parse the parameters (after checking).

When these parameters have been checked, they should be [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for [this reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Perform a search query, parse the results, and send the output back to the client (the user, browser).

Useful links:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 2):

you should look into implementing Ajax for this.

Here's a simple example and tutorial utilizing a drop down list that fetches information from a database on selection, without changing pages :)

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

You should also look into using jquery for your Ajax requests as stated in the answer below. (Do more with less code).

See also:
http://15daysofjquery.com/quick-and-dirty-ajax/14/ for a simple jquery Ajax tutorial.

Comment: @TMB : Good to know :)..however I believe this will help him understand the basics of the implementing ajax as it seems he hasn't before.With that being said,I wouldn't recommend copying and pasting code from any tutorial site without reviewing it thoroughly..

Comment: @TMB + Richard, apart from the lack of SQL injection protection what else would be wrong with the w3Schools example? I'm keen to find out what not to do just as much as what I want to do. =)

Comment: At a glance, no doctype, messy white space, and lack of SQL injection protection.  Although I can't speak to the SQL injection stuff to strongly. I really don't know PHP, but unless PHP handles it in the background, I don't see any. That stuff isn't even listed on w3fools.

Comment: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {...}` is missing a semicolon at the end of the function declaration

Comment: Okay, so nothing that some common sense wouldn't fix. Personally, I wouldn't expect them to add a doctype in every single example on the site, waste of space as you should know about doctypes if you're working with websites. And PHP doesn't handle any of it in the background, you need to put it in yourself, but that's not a problem as I know what I'm doing mostly with that case. =)

Cheers for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Before you render the page, make sure you do a grab the info you want presented from the database.

```
select distinct NAME, ID
from   tableName
```

You can use the information obtained here to generate the html for a drop down box. Include something to the effect

```
<select onchange="doAction(this.value);">
  <option value="userID">userName</option>
  <option value="userID">userName</option>
  <option value="userID">userName</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Then perform an [AJAX request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) back to your site. Get your information from your second query to the database, and return with the information you need.  When you perform your second query (and in general) you have to protect yourself against injection attack vectors.  The best start for this is to make sure you have encoded([HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx), [SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I can only really give you the below as a guide. It uses the jQuery load function to put the contents of one page into an element. Note that .load cannot be used across domains.

```
$("#searchButton").live("click", function() {
    $("#results").load("/SearchResults.php?s=" + $("#searchBox").val());
});
```

Also note that you should use something to filter out HTML tags to prevent SQL injection, as well as taking other measures.